# Super fast server for php script

Tags: php, hosting, bandwidth

I have a php script which requires no web hosting or disk space etc.
The script simply retrieves infromation from a server, does some processing on this information
and than passes it on to a client (an iPhone app in this case).
The only thing is that if traffic gets high than there is a high demand for bandwidth and speed.

Does anyone know of a service with high speed and badwidth (apart from web hosting services) that allows you to host (on a static ip) such a php script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try some sort of cloud service where you can set up the environment you actually need. Let's say your script need a lot of RAM but only little CPU power (or the other way around) you can have exactly such a system. [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) is one of many cloud computing providers out there.

Comment: You might even be able to run php on GoogleAppEngine, which would be perfect for your situation (or you rewrite your script in Python or Java).

Comment: GoogleAppEngine unfortunately does not yet have support for PHP but it would be great to use if it did.

Answer (score 1):

hmm the performance point you can use something like "Facebook HipHop" to convert your php script into "c++" then you have the performance you need.

Comment: Thanks Stony, the performance of the script is not such an issue but Facebook HipHop is really interesting and good to know about

Comment: HipHop is a cool think. I have testet some thinks. You have to look a lot that your application work but if you know the problems its working well.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud solution is perfect. You can even write shell scripts to increase decrease RAM whenever demand goes up.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone here mentioned, cloud hosting is your best bet. It's slightly more expensive for resources & bandwidth than a dedicated but is superior in performance/latency/scalability. I have a similar application setup for a current project and I am running on the RackSpace cloud with 100K+ active users on a daily basis and I have had no problems (been running for 6 months).

Answer (score 0):

If your code is simple, don't use Php !

You can consider:

- Python
- GWan server + C
- Java

Php is good for big project because its simple, fast to use/test/debug ...

Comment: G-WAN 3.10+ supports C, C#, Java... and PHP scripts. So you don't have to chose between speed and convenience.